# Django Model - cannot serialize into migration files

Tags: django, serialization, admin

I have 2 models Car and Offer. The car table is an existing table filled with vehicle specifications. In the django admin I want to map an offer to an existing car in the specs table. This means that when a click on an offer in admin, I want to be able to see a list with all cars - find the correct one - and save it on the offer. Ive done this by populating the foreignkey field with a list of choices based on the the existing car objects.

models.py:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.TextField(max_length=300, default= "")
    model = models.TextField(max_length=300, default= "")
    edition = models.TextField(max_length=300, default= "")
    engineVolume = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __unicode__(self):
      return smart_unicode(self.brand)

carIds = []
idx = 1
for car in Car.objects.all():
        carIds.append((idx,  car))
        idx = idx + 1


class Offer(models.Model):
    stringUrl = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    extractionDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    cars = models.ForeignKey(Car, default= "", choices=carIds, null=True, to_field='id')
```

this works perfectly. I click on an offer in admin and I see a selectionbox populated with all existing cars. I find the correct car, save it, and the offers´s foreignkey car id in the database points to the correct vehicle.
But suddenly when I want to make later migrations django says it cannot serialze the car object?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in    execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 143, in handle
self.write_migration_files(changes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 171, in write_migration_files
migration_string = writer.as_string()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 166, in as_string
operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 124, in serialize
_write(arg_name, arg_value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 87, in _write
arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(_arg_value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 377, in serialize
return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 268, in serialize_deconstructed
arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 303, in serialize
item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 303, in serialize
item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 465, in serialize
"topics/migrations/#migration-serializing" % (value, get_docs_version())
`enter code here`ValueError: Cannot serialize: <Car: Nissan>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-    serializing
```

I have no idea why this error occurs. I' m new to django and the just starting with the admin. I´ve been reading up on serialzation and deconstruction but cant see how to apply it here? Perhaps I should follow a different route to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you indent your code correctly?

Comment: @Ivan - identatation done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell you don't need `choices` at all.

`choices`, although can be any iterable and can be modified, is more suited for static data.

Afterwards, this piece of code

```
carIds = []
idx = 1
for car in Car.objects.all():
    carIds.append((idx,  car))
    idx = idx + 1
```

achieves nothing.

First, you are not filtering the choices in any way, just converting them to a list of tuples. Second, having a `ForeignKey` automatically provides choices from the referenced model's unfiltered queryset e.g. `Car.objects.all()`.

So you could just drop `choices`, and if you need filtering in `ModelForm` and admin use [`ForeignKey.limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) instead.

Comment: +1 Yeah, this is the right answer. Did just come to that realization when I was out smoking, but instead of editing my answer I will delete it.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I was tring to add a field like:

```
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Task.objects.first())
```

but corrected this by using:

```
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Task.objects.first().pk)
```

Comment: The down-side of this approach is that the migration file will be generated with a hard-coded primary key. If you're only managing one instance of your application this might be OK, but if you're developing on one instance and migrating to another instance then the default might end up being wrong.